# Get me started programming and debugging Microsoft Office automation

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I'm using Microsoft Office 2003 and creating a bunch of template documents to standardize some tasks.  I asked this on [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/66915/what-would-keep-a-microsoft-word-autonew-macro-from-running) and got no response so I'm thinking it's too program-y and hoping I'll have better luck here.

I need to automate a work flow that uses a bunch of Office (mostly Word) templates.  What I want is to have "My Template Foo.dot" and "My Template Bar.dot", etc. in the "My Foo Bar Stuff" on a shared drive and have users double click on a template to create a new Foo or Bar.

What's I'd really like is for the user to double-click on the Foo template and be prompted for a couple of items related to their task (e.g., a project number) and have a script in the template change the name that Save will default to something like "Foo for Project 1234.doc".

I asked on [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/browse_thread/thread/d52848f3e43af032?lnk=igtc) and got an answer that worked....for a while. Then my `AutoNew` macro stopped kicking in when I created a new document by double-clicking on the template.  I have no idea why or how to debug it.

In Class Modules/This Application, I have:

```
Sub AutoNew()
    Dim Project As String
    Project = InputBox("Enter the Project Number")
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs "Project " & Project & " Notes.doc"
End Sub
```

In Microsoft Word Objects/ThisDocument, I have:

```
Private Sub Document_New()

End Sub
```

I really have no idea why or where that came from.

In Tools/Macro Security... I have Security Level set to "Low".

I'm a software engineering with 25+ years of experience but a complete Office automation noob.  Specific solutions and pointers to "this is how to automate Word" FAQs are welcome. Thanks.

---

**Update:** If I create a new template (New..., Blank Document, Save As "My New Template.dot"), and insert the `AutoNew()` macro, it works.  So what's inhibiting it from working on my existing template?

**Update 2:** Removing the module and function from my old template and adding it back works, too.

Comment: Consider posting your code for the AutoNew macro.  My guess is it just got disconnected from the "autostart" functionality in Word, or you have some new security patch added from Microsoft that prevents the macro from starting.

Comment: @Robert - Or somebody turned off macros in the template and then saved over the template in the shared folder. I've seen that happen too many times to count.

Comment: @Justin: How do you turn off macros in the template?  Isn't that an application option?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a template to a saved document in ordre to access the macros contained in the template in question.

You can do this with the AttachedTemplate property of a Document object (i.e. ActiveDocument).
Please note that I did not try this myself.

```
Sub AutoNew()
   Dim Project As String
   Project = InputBox("Enter the Project Number")
   ActiveDocument.SaveAs "Project " & Project & " Notes.doc"

   ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = "\\path\to\templates\My Template Foo.dot"

End Sub
```

See [MSDN - Word 2003 VBA Language Reference - AttachedTemplate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212571%28office.11%29.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the macro is still contained in your template. This sounds stupid but it happended to me, too, in Word 2003 under the following circumstances:

1. Create a template containing macro,
   everything fine
2. Create a new document file based on
   the macro, macro kicks in
3. Notice I could improve the template
   here and there a bit, I do it in the
   file created in 2) and SaveAs .DOT
4. Macro in .DOT GONE!

Why? Because the code stored in the .DOT doesn't go over to the doc file.